# Template non-type pointer to arbitrary class method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Let's say I have:

```
struct Foo {
    void a();
    void b(const int& );
    int c();
};
```

I can create a function that takes as an argument an arbitrary pointer-to-`Foo` method:

```
template <typename R, typename... Formal, typename... Args>
R call(Foo* f, R (Foo::*method)(Formal...), Args&&... args) {
    return (f->*method)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int gratuitous = call(&some_foo, &Foo::c);
```

And I can create a function that takes a specific type of pointer-to-`Foo` method as a template:

```
template <void (Foo::*method)()>
void only_for_a(Foo *f) {
    (f->*method)();
}

only_for_a<&Foo::a>(&some_foo);
```

But is there a way to create a function that I can template on *any* pointer to class method? I want to be able to do:

```
works_for_anything<&Foo::a>(&some_foo);
works_for_anything<&Foo::b>(&some_foo, 42);
int result = works_for_anything<&Foo::c>(&some_foo);
```

Comment: No, non-type template parameters have to have a fixed type. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: what about `template<typename T, void(T::*medhod)()>`

Comment: @erenon I assume you mean `template <typename T, T method>`, but then the caller has to specify the type, e.g. `works_almost<decltype(&Foo::b), &Foo::b>(&some_foo, 42);`. But that seems redundant.

Comment: Maybe with C++1Z: `template <using typename R, using typename... Args, R(Foo::*method)(Args...)>`

Comment: Ugh, `using typename`, who likes that? Those keywords are already oversubscribed. Why not `template <auto Method>`?

Comment: @Barry: no, I meant what I've written.

Comment: @erenon Then that doesn't address the question at all. I wanted an arbitrarily typed class method - you're restricting to just nullary, void.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
template< typename T, T >
class works_for_anything_t;

template< typename R, typename... Args, R (*f)(Args...) >
class works_for_anything_t< R (*)(Args...), f >{
public:
  R operator()( Args... args ){ return f(args...); }
};

template< typename T, typename R, typename... Args, R (T::*f)(Args...) >
class works_for_anything_t< R (T::*)(Args...), f >{
public:
  R operator()( T& v, Args... args ) { return (v.*f)(args...); }

  works_for_anything_t(T& v)
   : v_(v) {  }
private:
  T& v_;
};

template< typename T, typename R, typename... Args, R (T::*f)(Args...) const >
class works_for_anything_t< R (T::*)(Args...) const, f >{
public:
  R operator()( const T& v, Args... args ) const { return (v.*f)(args...); }

  works_for_anything_t(const T& v)
   : v_(v) {  }
private:
  const T& v_;
};

#define works_for_anything(f) works_for_anything_t<decltype(&f), &f>

struct Foo {
    void a();
    void b(const int& );
    int c();
};

int test();

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  works_for_anything(Foo::b){foo}( 42 );
  works_for_anything(test){}();
  return 0;
}
```